# Migrating .net 2.0 console application on win 2008 r2

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nlog

I have some old 32bit console .NET 2.0 applications that should be migrated to win2008 r2 server.

***Note 1:*** I have one old 32bit application that doesn't load any assembly and is working correctly.

***Note 2:*** When I start one of the applications I get 
**System.BadImageFormatException Could not load file or assembly** error

***Note 3:***
Each of them are using **NLog** version 0.9.0.0. When I start these applications on our new server, I get following exception in nLOG.txt:

Error Could not load platform specific extensions: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at NLog.FilterFactory.AddFiltersFromAssembly(Assembly theAssembly, String prefix)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.LoadExtensionsFromAssembly(Assembly asm, String prefix)
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.RegisterPlatformSpecificExtensions(String name)

Can you please help us how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Deveti Putnik

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project settings, and make sure you build your target to 32-bit (x86), and "All Platforms".

The problem you're seeing is a 64-bit executable trying to access a 32-bit DLL. .NET executables by default run as 64-bit on 64-bit OSes.

Comment: I believe what you mean to say is "Any CPU" not "All Platforms" (unless this is only terminology I'm not aware of. Also ".NET executables run as 64-bit on 64-bit OSes" is contradictory, what I believe you mean is ".NET executables **compiled for 'AnyCPU'** by default run as 64-bit on 64-bit OSes". If this were true then he wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For  point 3:Why not Upgrade NLog to 2.0, For point 2: "System.BadImageFormatException Could not load file or assembly for which assembly" can you find out assemby name causing this problem,it  should be there in error message